# Navigation bar not covering status bar on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have a simple view controller with a view (map) pinned to its superview. The view is embedded on a navigation controller, but the navigation bar starts under the safe area (below status bar) on iPhone X. Ideally, I would like the bar to be under the status bar (not below it), when rendered on an iPhone X. How can I go about doing this?

[image]

This is how the bar is being set up to make it semi transparent:

```
//Design Set Up
let navBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: just to clarify: what do you think this does: `UINavigationBar.appearance()`?

Comment: Accesses and changes the appearance of the navigation bar across views

Comment: and `UINavigationBar` here is what? the object draw as black rectangle in your screenshot?

Comment: I am quite certain that you somehow managed to get a second navigation bar into your screen.

Comment: Not sure how that could happen

Comment: are u using xib files?

Comment: not custom ones

Comment: how do you embed you vc into the navigation controller?

Comment: Just selected it, and: Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.. I have also skipped using appearance() and accessed the navController.navigationBar from the view controller

Comment: did you ever drag some view into the vc?

Answer (score 1):

You should embed the view controller in a `UINavigationController`, not use just a `UINavigationBar`. That way you will automatically get a navigation bar with the navigation controller and it will extend fully to the top of the screen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

You can add it in a Storyboard or if you're using code, something like:

```
let mapViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MapViewController())
```

(assuming your map is called `MapViewController`)

Comment: I am embedding my view controller on a navigation controller, and changing its appearance on AppDelegate